# SQL Average Bookings per day

Tags: sql, average

I am trying to workout the average number of bookings made per day over a given time period.

So far I have this code:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(NumberOfBookings) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATEPART(weekday, UpdatedDate) AS Days, 
         COUNT(*) AS NumberOfBookings
     FROM 
         Booking
     WHERE 
         Status = 'Confirmed'    
     GROUP BY 
         DATEPART(weekday, UpdatedDate)) AS COUNTS
```

When I run it I just get 1 result which is the average of all bookings per day rather than an individual average for each day of the week.

I also tried running this:

```
SELECT Days,
       AVG(NumberOfBookings) 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATEPART(weekday,UpdatedDate) AS Days, 
         COUNT(*) AS NumberOfBookings
    FROM 
         Booking
    WHERE 
         Status = 'Confirmed'    
    GROUP BY
         DATEPART(weekday,UpdatedDate)) AS COUNTS
GROUP BY
    Days
```

But this just gives me the total from each day rather than the average.

The Bookings table includes these columns: BookingID, BookingDate, CustomerID, UpdatedDate, Status

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the structure of table `Booking`, i.e. the column names and their data types. You should also post some sample data from table `Booking` as well as your expected result based on that sample data. Lastly, you should also post the DBMS you are using. Refer to [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Please provide table structur, a sample of data, and a sample of the result that you want. That is good of us to provide a better answer.

Comment: It is hard to tell without the structure of the table, But you are having two `SELECT` statements whereby the outer is not grouped by the day., so it takes the average over everything and not per day.

Comment: You asked for "average of all bookings per day". You need another GROUP BY.'

Comment: A [mcve] would make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select  t.NameOfDay,t.PerDayBookings, t.TotalBookings
from (
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[BookingStartDateTime] ) as NameOfDay,
    count(*) as PerDayBookings,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() AS TotalBookings
  FROM [Bookings]
  Where [BookingStartDateTime] is not null
  Group by DATENAME(weekday,[BookingStartDateTime] ) 
  
  )as t
```

Answer (score 0):

I counted the number of `confirmed` per day and then divided by `distinct time` to get the average.

```
select   datepart(weekday, time)                                   as day_of_the_week     
        ,cast(1.0*count(*)/count(distinct time) as decimal (10,2)) as avg_confirmed_per_day
from     t
where    status = 'confirmed'
group by datepart(weekday, time)
```

| day_of_the_week | avg_confirmed_per_day |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 1.00 |
| 6 | 1.00 |
| 7 | 1.50 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZmINH-Ps)